# unable to upload the pdf document in .net 2.0 and getting exception error

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I have developed a application where i am uploading the PDF files and binding it to Gridview. I can upload less size files like up to 3.5MB after that i can not upload PDF file as i get error message like "Server Error in '/STAT' Application. Runtime Error" or "Page can not be displayed (while testing in local system)"

Technologies used :
vs 2005
.net 2.0 and it is web application.

I have pasted the code below which i wrote :

```
Protected Sub btnUploadSTPI_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)   Handles btnUploadSTPI.Click
    Try
        If txtStpiRegNo.Text <> "" Then
            If txtfilepathSTPI.Value <> "" Then
                Dim objDS As DataSet
                Dim UploadFile, UploadPath, strFile, sUploadPath, sUploadfilename As String
                Dim arr As Array
                UploadFile = txtfilepathSTPI.Value
                UploadPath = UploadFile.LastIndexOf("\") + 1
                strFile = UploadFile.Substring(UploadPath)
                sUploadPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("UploadTempFile").ToString()
                arr = strFile.Split(".")
                strFile = CType(arr(0).ToString() + "_" + txtStpiRegNo.Text + "_" + System.DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() + "." + arr(1).ToString, String)
                sUploadfilename = sUploadPath + strFile
                txtfilepathSTPI.PostedFile.SaveAs(sUploadfilename)
                objDS = Session("TempDS")
                If objDS.Tables.Count > 1 Then
                    Dim objRow As DataRow
                    objRow = objDS.Tables(1).NewRow()
                    objRow.Item("UploadFileName") = arr(0).ToString()
                    objRow.Item("UploadFilePath") = strFile
                    objRow.Item("CompanyID") = ddlCompany.SelectedValue
                    objRow.Item("CompanyDocuments") = "STPI REG NO - " + txtStpiRegNo.Text
                    objDS.Tables(1).Rows.InsertAt(objRow, objDS.Tables(1).Rows.Count + 1)
                    dgCompanyFiles.DataSource = objDS.Tables(1)
                    dgCompanyFiles.DataBind()
                    Session("TempDS") = objDS
                End If
            Else
                lblError.Text = "Please select a file to upload."
            End If
        Else
            lblError.Text = "Please enter STPI REG No."
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Even I tried tracking the application and it is not going to the particular button event after browsing the file and clicking on the Upload button for larger file size more then 3.5MB..

Error Message :

```
Server Error in '/STAT' Application.
```

Runtime Error 
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to edit web.config to enable viewing errors. The method for doing this is displayed in the reported error itself.

Second, you need to allow larger upload file sizes:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxx" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks Juannn... It is working fine

I had given <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" />

Its taking the file thanks a lot...